# ServiceReference not found when return a DataContract from a OperationContract?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

It is a simple class, I reference it in silverlight project in the same solution. if the operation method returns an integer, it works fine, but if I make it return a DataContract, it just says the servicereference cannot find

In web project

```
  public class UserResult
  {
....
  }
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class ServiceUser
  {
       [OperationContract]
     public UserResult UserSignIn(string userid, string password)
     {
      ...
     } /// doesn't work

    public int UserSignIn(string userid, string password)
    {
   ...
    } // works
```

In SilverLight

```
  ServiceReferenceUser.ServiceUserClient srUser = 
      new ServiceReferenceUser.ServiceUserClient();
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work (what does "says the service reference cannot find" mean)? Can you post the full error, whether it's in the "Add Service Reference" dialog (full message), or at runtime (full exception message, including stack trace)?

Comment: The error is "the type or namespace 'ServiceReferenceUser' cannot be found"

Comment: Well, the namespace `ServiceReferenceUser` doesn't exist, so you cannot use it. Try opening the file Reference.cs (which you can see if you select the "Show All Files" option in the VS project), and see which namespace the class was created under.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the UserResult class references some other DataContract. If so, that DataContract needs to be specified as a known type.